# Why do I get the error "! Illegal parameter number in definition of \appendix."while redefining the \appendix command?

Tags: macros, chapters

I'm trying to redefine the `\appendix` command so that my appendix headings go to the top of the pages. To do this, I tried the following code, but I get the error `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \appendix`. Why am I getting this error and how to get rid of it?

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{0\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \gdef\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
  \gdef\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\appendix
\chapter{Foo}
\end{document}
```

Please keep in mind that, I know that a solution is to put the redefinition of the `\@makechapterhead` at the beginning of the `\appendix` command in the document body, but I want to do the job in the preamble. Also, I'd prefer not to use extra packages to do the job.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Inside the definition of `\appendix`, `#1` would be the first parameter of `\appendix` that does not exists, `\appendix` is defined without parameters. For the parameters of a definition inside a definition you need to double the hash char:

```
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
  \def\@makechapterhead##1{%
    ... ##1 ...
  }%
  ...
}
```

If `\@makechapterhead` contained another definition with a parameter, then `####` would be needed for the inner parameter.

Comment: This really helped me with the todonotes package. If you want \todo{Here is some \lstinline{SomeClass#SomeMethod}}, you have to escape the # or todonotes gets confused e.g. \todo{Here is some \lstinline{SomeClass\#SomeMethod}}. HTH future travelers