# Illegal parameter number in definition of \enit@before. You meant to type ## instead of #, right?

Tags: errors, enumerate, compiling, enumitem, compilation-error

I am trying to renew the `\item` command, inside the `\setlist` command for [How to create a enumerate list adding a custom prefix before each item number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512123/how-to-create-a-enumerate-list-adding-a-custom-prefix-before-each-item-number), but latex keeps telling me:

```
test1.tex:22: Illegal parameter number in definition of \enit@before
You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.
```

But I am already typing `##`. I also tried typing `###`, `####` and `#####`, but the error still the same. If I replace the `##` by a single one `#`, then, latex stops creating the PDF correctly. As it is now, the PDF is generated correctly, even with that error popping up.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcounter{descriptcount}
\newlist{enumdescript}{description}{1}

\setlist[enumdescript,1]{%
  before={%
    \setcounter{descriptcount}{0}%
    \renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\arabic{descriptcount}}%
    \let\olditem\item%
    \renewcommand{\item}[1][]{%
       \olditem##1\space\stepcounter{descriptcount}\thedescriptcount)\xspace}%
  },
  after={\let\item\olditem},
  align=left
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumdescript}
   \item one
   \item two
   \item[Some Text] three
   \item four
   \item five
\end{enumdescript}
\end{document}
```

## Related questions

1. [Error: Illegal Parameter number in definition of \iterate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420448/error-illegal-parameter-number-in-definition-of-iterate)
2. [How to fix Illegal parameter number in definition of a new Tikz command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367918/how-to-fix-illegal-parameter-number-in-definition-of-a-new-tikz-command)
3. [href: Illegal parameter number in definition of \test](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401742/href-illegal-parameter-number-in-definition-of-test)
4. [! Illegal parameter number in definition of \NewValue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225761/illegal-parameter-number-in-definition-of-newvalue)
5. [Error: Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387936/error-illegal-parameter-number-in-definition-of-reserveda)
6. [hyperref error using latex: "Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@temp"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173758/hyperref-error-using-latex-illegal-parameter-number-in-definition-of-hytemp)
7. [! Illegal parameter number in definition of \abx@list@location](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469720/illegal-parameter-number-in-definition-of-abxlistlocation)
8. [LaTeX error: illegal parameter number in definition of \pgffor@b](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450308/latex-error-illegal-parameter-number-in-definition-of-pgfforb)
9. [Why do I get the error "! Illegal parameter number in definition of \appendix."while redefining the \appendix command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99608/why-do-i-get-the-error-illegal-parameter-number-in-definition-of-appendix-w)
10. [Error "! Illegal parameter number in definition of \ tikz @ children @ list." with library mindmap and hyperref packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479378/error-illegal-parameter-number-in-definition-of-tikz-children-list-wi)
11. ["! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a" working with fncychap](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508672/illegal-parameter-number-in-definition-of-reserveda-working-with-fncychap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With these keys it is sometimes hard to guess at which level one is, so I suggest to use

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcounter{descriptcount}
\newlist{enumdescript}{description}{1}

\def\renewitem{%
  \setcounter{descriptcount}{0}%
  \renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\arabic{descriptcount}}%
  \let\olditem\item%
  \renewcommand{\item}[1][]{%
    \olditem##1\space\stepcounter{descriptcount}\thedescriptcount)\xspace%
  }%
}
\setlist[enumdescript,1]{%
  before={\renewitem},
  after={\let\item\olditem},
  align=left,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumdescript}
   \item one
   \item two
   \item[Some Text] three
   \item four
   \item five
\end{enumdescript}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I did not know I had to keep trying adding more `#`. After trying up, I figured out it works after adding 6 `#` as in `######1`

Comment: @user Yes. The problem, though, is that the number may change if you, say, put this in a foreach loop. This is why I usually do things as indicated in the answer. This has the additional benefit that you could locally redefine the macro. (Of course you may want to put \let\olditem=\item only once in the preamble.)